# Ruby on Rails: How can I specify runner script environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, bash

I am using a shell script to run some runner scripts in my Ruby on Rails app. I need to run it on the production database, but the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/ruby RAILS_ENV=production ../script/runner ../lib/tasks.rb
```

gives an error:

```
/usr/bin/ruby: No such file or directory -- RAILS_ENV=production (LoadError)
```

I have tried to force it in config/environment.rb

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'production'
```

or even

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] = 'production'
```

but even with that it still runs in development environment.

Update: I can force the scripts to connect to the right database by editing the config/database.yml file, but I wonder what's the proper way of doing it.

Comment: Have you read my response? It will choose your environment correctly if you pass your parameters differently.

Comment: It will run, but it will not set the environment correctly.

Comment: Then something is wrong with your script, not the command.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The help on the command line for script/runner gives you your answer.

```
script/runner -e production Model.method
```

Comment: Faced the same issue. This solution worked for me. Thanks. +1

Comment: Don't have a script/runner, but script/rails runner -e production Model.method works for me.

Comment: neither ``script/runner -e production Model.method`` nor ``script/rails runner -e production Model.method`` worked for me... the following did work though: ``RAILS_ENV=production rails runner -e production Model.method``

Answer (score 5):

If that's your command, the order of your arguments is your biggest problem.

```
/usr/bin/ruby RAILS_ENV=production ../script/runner ../lib/tasks.rb
```

Is different than.

```
/usr/bin/ruby ../script/runner ../lib/tasks.rb RAILS_ENV=production
```

The second example is looking for the file, the first one is setting a runtime variable while ruby interpreting it as the file you want to run.

Answer (score 5):

If you redo your script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
RAILS_ENV=production
/usr/bin/ruby ../script/runner ../lib/tasks.rb
```

...that will make it stick for the lifetime of the script. To make it stick for the lifetime of the shell's session, change it to

```
#!/bin/bash
export RAILS_ENV=production
/usr/bin/ruby ../script/runner ../lib/tasks.rb
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the environment variable like this :

```
RAILS_ENV=production /usr/bin/ruby ../script/runner ../lib/tasks.rb
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RAILS_ENV=production script/rails runner 'user = User.find(:first, :conditions => {:admin => true}) ; user.password, user.password_confirmation = "mypasswd"; user.save!'
```

it worked for me